# Spring Error occurred during initialization of boot layer In Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

when I download the files of Spring and added them to eclipse I get this error for the "Hello World" project;

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Program 
Files\eclipse\spring-framework-5.1.9.RELEASE\libs\spring-context-indexer-5.1.9.RELEASE-sources.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class 
org.springframework.context.index.processor.CandidateComponentsIndexer not in module
```

Answer (score 0):

follow those steps to solve the problem;

1- download the lastes version of Spring in [her](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/) (in my case it was, "`5.2.0.RELEASE/ 30-Sep-2019 09:06`") chose the `spring-X.x.x.RELEASE-dist.zip`.

2- Unzip the files.

3- in eclipse add extranl jars [Steps](https://www.websparrow.org/misc/how-to-create-user-library-in-eclipse-ide) In the Libs folder, don't take the ones with `spring-xxx-X.x.x.RELEASE-sources`.

4- done.